# drop down box's width of bootstrap token field can't be fit in a invisible div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tokenfield

I've used [Bootstrap Token Field](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) at my website. It works perfectly at my webpage. But, problem happened when I put that token field into any hidden div. I mean, imagine there is a hidden div(`display: none;`) Inside that invisible div, I've put the token filed box. That hidden div will visible after clicking a button. At that time, if I notice the dropdown box/autocomplete suggestion box of the token field box, I see that the width of that dropdown box can't get a full width where at the default state it's perfect. I'm showing you a picture so that you can be more clear.

This is the normal condition of token field:

[image]

This is the condition if it's stayed in a invisible div. Look, the width of drop down box isn't 100% according to the input field:

[image]

Here is my fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/qV2E2/

Click the "Show" link, to make visible the invisible div

I don't understand why it's happened! How can I make the drop down box's width similar to input field's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/k8AKL/) if you want to make it work. Just execute the javascript after you display the hidden div, so you will have:

```
<div class="default">
    <input type="text" class="form-control tokenfield1" value="" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="show pull-right">Show</a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="another">
    <input type="text" class="form-control tokenfield2" value="" />
</div>
```

And:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $('.another').slideToggle();
    $('.tokenfield2').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['Red City','Blue City','United Kingdom','Australia','United Sates','Finland','Bulgeriya','Hungary','Istambul'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
});

$('.tokenfield1').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['Red City','Blue City','United Kingdom','Australia','United Sates','Finland','Bulgeriya','Hungary','Istambul'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for you click function. It gets the outer width of the input field with the class `tokenfield` and assigns that width to the other input field

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    var width = $('.tokenfield').outerWidth();
    $('.another input').width(width);
    $('.another').slideToggle();
});
```